# AngularJs pass parameter into the then

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a script that is getting a list of items then for each item i get the data then need to combine the definition and the data to one object

Parts in the code:
I would like to pass `itemObject` to the  `DashboardFactory.Convert` function

Is that possible? or is there a better way to go about this?

Currently it has the value of the last item in the items array due to the promise mechanic

```
var items = BaseFunctionsService.GetData(result);
console.log('success', items);
if (items)
{
    var itemdata = null;
    var chartData = null;
    var itemData = null;
    var itemObject = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        itemObject = items[i];
        itemData = DashboardFactory.GetData(items[i]);

        itemData.then(function (result) {
            console.log('itemdata result', result);
            itemdata = BaseFunctionsService.GetData(result);
            chartData = DashboardFactory.Convert(itemObject, itemdata, result.data.Translations[result.data.LangKey]);
            console.log('itemdata success', chartData);
            $scope.data.push(chartData);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log('itemdata error', error);
        });
    }
    console.log('data output', $scope.data);
}
```

Comment: you could do `DasboardFactory.Convert.call(itemObject, /*rest of arguments*/)` or you could use `DashboardFactory.Convert.bind(itemObject)`, which would make the `this` reference in that function reference the `itemObject`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an IIEF in your for loop to keep the correct reference to `itemObject` when `itemData` promise is resolved, this is a common bug with closures in for loops.

```
var items = BaseFunctionsService.GetData(result);
console.log('success', items);
if (items)
{
    var itemdata = null;
    var chartData = null;
    var itemData = null;
    var itemObject = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) (function (i) {
        itemObject = items[i];
        itemData = DashboardFactory.GetData(items[i]);

        itemData.then(function (result) {
            console.log('itemdata result', result);
            itemdata = BaseFunctionsService.GetData(result);
            chartData = DashboardFactory.Convert(itemObject, itemdata, result.data.Translations[result.data.LangKey]);
            console.log('itemdata success', chartData);
            $scope.data.push(chartData);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log('itemdata error', error);
        });
    })(i);
    console.log('data output', $scope.data);
}
```